# how to insert data in two tables with one query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i have two tables `stock` and `purchase` table
i want that when data is been inserted into the `purchase` table the `stock` table 
should be updated with the insertion of the `purchase` table how to do it?

Comment: what DBMS you are using?

Comment: using sql server 2012

Comment: You can use triggers

Comment: Most likely SQL triggers on INSERT action will work for you.

Comment: can you give an example query for it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask], and [edit] your question with the relevant tables create statements, the data you want to insert to the purchase table, and the effect you want it to have on the stock table. Also, It would help to see what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_stock
AFTER INSERT
ON purchase
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO stock (att1, att2)
    SELECT att1,att2 FROM INSERTED
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_int
ON purchase
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO stock (order_id, name, price)
    SELECT
      order_id,
      name,
      price
    FROM INSERTED
END
```

Comment: @SamiJavaid  Hope its useful. Visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers